# Strange try..catch behaviour with async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception

I'm starting to play around with .NET 4.5, especially the async/await features.

I came to the code below, which to my suprise, compiles. Can anyone explain to my why?

```
async Task SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

With previous .NET versions the compiler would complain with a message similar to: "not all of the paths return value".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An async method returning `Task` is equivalent to a normal method returning `void`. There's nothing try/catch-specific here - don't forget that your `try` block doesn't return anything either!

So the non-async version of your code would just be:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

... and obviously that would compile. (Equally obviously, it's horrible to use use a bare `catch`, but I assume that's not really the question :)

*This* code won't compile:

```
async Task<int> SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 10;
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks clear now. Can you give me a link to some article which discusses in details what happens, behind the scenes, with async/await?

Comment: @dzendras: MSDN will have a lot, but you could also read my Eduasync series: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx Note that the feature has changed a little over time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at those.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question to Jon's answer, I add these links for better readability as a separate answer.

For getting more info on what happens behind the scenes I would like to point you these articles from the MSDN magazine that helped me getting started with it:

MSDN October 2011 issue: [Parallel Programming with .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/03/10219193.aspx)

1. [Pause and Play with Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456403.aspx)
2. [Async Performance: Understanding the Costs of Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)
3. [Easier Asynchronous Programming with the New Visual Studio Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456401.aspx)

Especially the first two articles might be what you are looking for as they describe better how the compiler rewrites your code internally to make `async/ await` work.